# Efecto parallax pero con cabecera y menús fijos

Tags: html, html5, css3

Tengo una cabecera y un menú que quiero que estén fijados a la parte de arriba. Luego, quiero poner una serie de fotos que ocupen toda la pantalla y vayan pasando de una a otra con el efecto parallax según el usuario baja el scroll.

El problema principal es que quiero que la primera fotografía empiece donde empieza el body y que el menú, que tiene un poco de transparencia, quede por encima. No soy capaz de conseguirlo, ¿alguna idea o pista?

Tengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que la foto 1 quede debajo del body y ocupe toda la pantalla y el resto vayan pegadas una debajo de otras tal y como la imagen.

El código:

```css
body {}

div.padre {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: rgba(15, 15, 15, 1);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.hijo1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  top: 5px;
}

.hijo2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 5px;
}

.hijo1>p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: grey;
}

.hijo2>p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.hijo1>p>a,
.hijo2>p>a {
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.icon-phone {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#tel {
  font-size: 17px;
}

.cabecera {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.95);
  display: block;
  /* poner inlineblock para espacio en cabecera*/
  /* margin-bottom: 2px; separación cabecera */
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

nav.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.75);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul#navegador {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 16px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a.letra_nav {
  font-size: 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}


/*--------------------------Body--------------------------*/

.sector {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  background: black;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <div class="padre">
      <div class="hijo1">
        <p><a href=""><span class="icon-phone"></span></a></p>
        <p id="tel"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="hijo2">
        <p><a href=""><span class="icon-facebook3"></span></a></p>
        <p><a href=""><span class="icon-twitter2"></span></a></p>
        <p><a href=""><span class="icon-gmail"></span></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cabecera"><img id="logo" src="logo_transparente3.png" alt=""></div>

    <nav class="menu">
      <ul id="navegador">
        <li><a class="letra_nav" href="">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a class="letra_nav" href="">El local</a></li>
        <li><a class="letra_nav" href="">La carta</a></li>
        <li><a class="letra_nav" href="">Grupos</a></li>
        <li><a class="letra_nav" href="">A domicilio</a></li>
        <li><a class="letra_nav" href="">Reservas</a></li>
        <li><a class="letra_nav" href="">Dónde estamos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>

  <div>
    <div class="sector">Foto 1</div>
    <div class="sector">Foto 2</div>
    <div class="sector">Foto 3</div>
    <div class="sector">Foto 4</div>
    <div class="sector">Foto 5</div>
    <div class="sector">Foto 6</div>
  </div>

  <footer>

  </footer>
```

Comment: Hola MeN. ¿Podrías publicar el código que tienes hasta ahora? Así se me hace mas fácil ayudarte :)

Comment: Si, claro. He editado mi mensaje principal, ahi lo tienes. Aun no se bien como publicar codigo en strackoverflow, nunca queda como quiero.

Comment: solo usa la propiedad `position: fixed` en la etiqueta `header`

Comment: te dejo una desmostracion y codigo que podrias utilizar para hacer lo que deseas [Demo](https://tympanus.net/Development/HeaderEffects/) y [descarga](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/16/on-scroll-header-effects/)